# What issues could cause both stop codes of 7F and 116?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I'm working with a computer that had 3 recent BSODS.  The first crash 3 days ago gave a 7F error with ntoskrnl.exe, which is hardly helpful.  The crashes 2 and 1 day ago were with a 116 error, indicating video issues - bluescreenviewer listed dxgkrnl.sys.  Could driver issues cause both error codes to intermittently happen?  I cannot reproduce any of the BSODs.

EDIT:

7/2: 070215-32339-01.dmp    7/2/2015 1:11:48 PM UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP 0x0000007f  0000000000000008    0000000080050033    00000000000006f8    fffff808030c9888    ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+748c0  NT Kernel & System  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Microsoft Corporation   6.1.7601.18869 (win7sp1_gdr.150525-0603)    x64     C:\Windows\Minidump\070215-32339-01.dmp 2   15  7601

7/3: 070315-23587-01.dmp    7/3/2015 11:49:48 PM        0x00000116  fffffa80037fe4e0    fffff88003e0c80c    0000000000000000    0000000000000002    dxgkrnl.sys dxgkrnl.sys+5d134                   x64     C:\Windows\Minidump\070315-23587-01.dmp 2   15  7601

7/4: 070415-20794-01.dmp    7/4/2015 9:12:09 AM     0x00000116  fffffa8003c14180    fffff8800408780c    0000000000000000    0000000000000002    dxgkrnl.sys dxgkrnl.sys+5d134                   x64     C:\Windows\Minidump\070415-20794-01.dmp 2   15  7601

Comment: What are the complete error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: I copied the top entries directly.  If you need more info, I apologize, I'll try to get it.

Comment: Bugcheck 7F with reason code 8 (double fault exception) almost invariably indicates a kernel stack overflow. However this can be caused by a variety  of coding errors. Can you post the minidump files somewhere?

Comment: `dxgkrnl.sys` suggest a graphics driver issue (dxgkrnl == DirectX Graphics Kernel System Driver); recommend getting the latest graphics drivers, or if you've updated recently, try downgrading ..

Answer (score 0):

Did some research

STOP **0x0000007F** (UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP)

### CAUSE

This error message can occur if either of the following conditions exists: 
Your computer has hardware or software problems (hardware failure is the most common cause).

- You try to over clock the speed of your computer's processor (for
  example, you set a 150 MhZ processor to run at 187 MhZ). The above
  STOP error means a trap occurred in kernel mode and the trap is
  either one the kernel is not allowed to have or is always fatal. The
  most common causes of a STOP 0x7F are:
- Low-level hardware corruption,
  such as corrupt memory (RAM)
- Mismatched memory modules
- A malfunctioning motherboard

Your specific case is  **0x00000008** means: Double Fault

### Double fault

A double fault occurs when an exception occurs while trying to call the handler for a prior exception. Normally, the two exceptions can be handled serially, however there are several exceptions that cannot be handled serially and in this situation the processor signals a double fault. The two primary causes for this are hardware and kernel stack overflows. Hardware problems are usually related to CPU, RAM, or bus. Kernel stack overflows are almost always caused by faulty kernel-mode drivers.

### RESOLUTION

To resolve this issue, use the appropriate method:

- If either software or hardware can cause a particular trap, a debug is required to determine which is the cause. If you suspect a hardware problem, try the following hardware troubleshooting steps:

  1. Test the RAM in the computer by running the diagnostic software that is provided by the computer manufacturer. Replace any RAM that is reported as bad. Also, make sure that all the RAM in the computer is the same speed.
  2. Try removing or swapping out controllers, cards, or other peripherals.
  3. Try a different motherboard on the computer.
- If you are over clocking the speed of your processor, set it back to the speed at which it is designed to run.
- Check with the hardware vendor for any updated hardware drivers or BIOS updates, or both.

---

**0x00000116**

This error occurs when there is a compatibility issue between the graphic card, the hardware or its driver.

What You should do is go to device manager, uninstall the display driver and do a restart.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPt78weVKac